# What is the affect of reading from Accelerometer on battery?

Tags: android

I am planning an application that will read data from the accelerometer 24/7 and wanted to know if it has a huge affect on the battery life of the device (like GPS does)?

For anyone that has done something similar - any insight?

Thanks.

(FYI: I don't have an Android device yet so can't do my own testing)

Comment: Do you want to check sometimes (like once per hour) for checking if the devices move or do you want to check every "milliseconds" for acceleration inside the device ? in the first choice the impact depends on the frequency, but in the other choice it should impact a lot.

Comment: Well I am looking to do fall detection (ie has the phone been dropped)....so I am assuming I will have to have a sample at least every 0.5s...would that make sense?

Comment: I don't know, but i think it will use a lot of battery if a service should check "continuously" if the phone is dropped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getPower()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#getPower%28%29)

> the power in mA used by this sensor while in use

So test it yourself and let us know how it works out :)

---

edit: Oh you don't have a device. [This article is informative](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/10/workaround-for-minimizing-sensor.html)

The [presentation related to this blog post](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/10/my-presentation-about-motion.html) is worth reading too.